# Can an array of data be assigned single value in GraphQL Schema?

Tags: graphql

When assigning types to your data model in GraphQL, Is there a way I can assign an array of of defined types to a larger type? Sorry I don't really know the best way to word the question. Example Below.

```
type Creature {
  id: ID! @unique
  creature_name: String!
  creature_type: String!
  creature_size: String!
  description: String!
  creature_stats: [Health: Int!, Stamina: Int!, Endurance: Int!...]
}
```

I am wanting to call the creature_stats and get back all the stats in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what I think you are looking for is a relation to another data model. You could do something like:

```
type Creature {
  id: ID! @unique
  creature_name: String!
  creature_type: String!
  creature_size: String!
  description: String!
  creature_stats: CreatureStats!
}

type CreatureStats {
  id: ID! @unique
  Health: Int!
  Stamina: Int!
  Endurance: Int!
  ...
}
```

I hope it helps.